# IntelliJ with one Maven project depending on another Maven project: How to be efficient?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My team is regularly facing inconveniences when running a Maven project that depends on other Maven projects which were modified but not reinstalled to the local repository.

For the sake of simplification, let's say I have two Maven projects *Business* and *Web*. My *Web* project has in its dependencies the *Business* project, and a Jetty plugin which allows me to run a local web server for development.

In IntelliJ, both projects are opened on the same window using Maven Add project, so that I can navigate through the code easily between the two projects.

Currently, I have set up a Run Configuration in IntelliJ so that `mvn clean install -DskipTests` will run on the *Business* project, and then `mvn clean jetty:run` on *Web*. This allows me to run *Web* with the latest modifications made in *Business*. If I don't run `clean install` on the *Business* project, then *Web* will run on an older version of the source code of *Business*. In addition this will mess up the IntelliJ debugger as the source code being debugged will not match the runtime class.

In a real application, a *Dependency Injection Bootstrap* project may depend on *Web*, *Business*, *Some Database Adapter X*, *Some Database Adapter Y*, *Some API Client Adapter*... therefore the `clean install` may become costly. In addition it is easy to forget to build the dependee project, which is the reason why the Maven goals are always run before running Jetty.

Is there a way to be more efficient during development, so that a modification on a dependee project will be active when running the dependant projects without having to run any/many Maven goals?

Comment: It sounds like you should get those projects which depend on another into a single multi module build....that will make the handling easier...

Comment: @khmarbaise We were already using multi module builds and opening the root project in IntelliJ. The issue is resolved now, as I have set up a Jetty Run Configuration (as opposed to running a Maven goal to run Jetty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a tiny parent project pom.xml which references both Business and Web as modules.  Then tell Intellj to open the parent project - this will let Web access Business (if properly referenced) without having to install the artifacts locally.

Comment: This is already the case. Am I missing something here? I have reproduced the following as an example: https://github.com/Hurricaaane/maven-deptest/blob/master/pom.xml Not only am I getting `Failed to execute goal on project web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:business:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` when `jetty:run` on *Web* if I don't install the artifacts locally, any modification I make to a class in *Business* will not be reflected after `jetty:run` on *Web* if I don't install the artifact locally.

Comment: If you have the two projects in separate IntelliJ windows they cannot see each other.

Comment: Ah, you need this to work with jetty:run.  That does not pick up changes in Maven dependencies, just in the local project file system.  You may want to run Jetty inside Intellij instead - this will give you the full power of the IDE.  The best webserver experience I've seen so far is with Netbeans bundled with Glassfish.  Everything just work.s

Comment: Oh, wow, I don't know why this hasn't occurred to me... This may be just good enough for us! I will try this approach at work tomorrow. You may edit your answer so that it mentions avoiding using jetty:run, then I'll be able to accept it if I see that it works and if no one else answered with an alternative better approach.

Comment: I created a Run Configuration based on Jetty, and it does work, including with hot code swap. Thanks!